# Pooled OLS vs Random Effects difference in coefficients

Tags: least-squares, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model, pooling

My lecture slides say that a reason for why coefficients for some of the Pooled OLS model and Random Effects are different in a specific example could be because unobserved time-invariant factors are positively correlated with the regressors for which those coefficients are different.

However, this does not make a lot of sense to me. If this would be the case (i.e. $\operatorname{Cov}[\alpha_i,x_i]$, wouldn't BOTH random effects as well as Pooled OLS be biased?